# Swift Background Image Dropping FPS / Texture Change Causing Lag

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm building my first game in Swift so please go easy... I've put together a game that runs pretty well, when I add a background image to my GameScene, it basically drops the FPS by 30-40%. The background image is 225KB.

I've added the following to didMoveToView:

```
var background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg");
background.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 2)
background.size = self.frame.size
self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill
self.addChild(background)
```

In `touchesEnded`

On each click I'm changing the texture like so:

```
projectile.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "rabbit")
```

Is this the right way to change each time there's a click?

The reason I've set the background here is because every time I set the background in the GameViewController, it covers my GameScene and I've tried using z-index and sending the background to the back but I had no luck after 1-2 hours of trying.

I have a strong feeling this is what is dropping my FPS because it's another SKSpriteNode - even when I start up the game it lags.

Is there a way in instruments to see what line of code or block of code is causing the lag?

Is there a better way to assign this background to reduce lag? I'm using around 15 small images and each 10 seconds I'm switching a texture--could that be why? I also feel that switching a texture each 10 seconds could be causing this.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you testing in simulator or on device?

Comment: It's very slow on the simulator but not as slow on the device.

Comment: I've a lot going on within the main thread, should I use different threads?

Comment: What sort of things are you doing on the main thread?

Comment: Are you using a texture atlas for your textures? Or individual images?

Comment: Note that 225 kb is the size of an image when stored on disk. When image is stored in memory, things are different. To calculate amount of memory required to store an image you should use this formula : width x height x bytes per pixel. Standard 32-bit 2048x2048 image will require about 16 megabytes when stored in memory.

Comment: Using a sprite node for the BG is correct, and shouldn't be lagging you out just from adding it to the scene. Do you have a lot of other stuff happening in your game start code?

Comment: Added threading and it seems to have solved that issue! Is around 40FPS good for a game? For some reason when I do a segue programatically it just freezes my game, any ideas?